# Vertical-align a background-image with a sibling div containing a variable size text

Tags: html, css

I've been struggling with an eternal problem : **vertical alignment**.

For now I've used a lot of tricks as the `display: table-cell;` or the amazing `flex`, but this time I can't find a proper solution :

#### Problem

I've got a container `div` with two children, one is a `div` with a `background-image` and the other one contain a `h2` title and a `p` with a **variable size** text.

#### Goal

**Vertically align** the `background-image` whatever the text size is, without having to specify a `background-size`other than contain or a `min-height` to the image container.

#### Code

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="text">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>
      Variable length text
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper{
  width : 100%;
}
.wrapper div{
  display: inline-block;
}
.image{
  width: 20%;
  background-image: url('path/to/img.jpg');
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  min-height:100px; // Not displaying without
}
.text{
  width: 60%;
}
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pxs8jsmo/) to see it in action. I've read a tremendous number of questions related to this problem, read them long time ago too, but didn't find one about this.

By advance, thanks !

### Edit

There's a way of doing it with `flex` display by adding to the `.wrapper` :

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

But it still use a `min-height`to display the `background-image` and I would like it to have a `background-size : contain;` [updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pxs8jsmo/4/)

Comment: no problem with `jquery` ?

Comment: Only `css` if possible

Comment: So what is the problem here https://jsfiddle.net/pxs8jsmo/5/ ?

Comment: @NenadVracar I think he want something like this but only with `css` [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jiffiddle/pxs8jsmo/6/) @PaulCo right?

Comment: @NenadVracar Yes, I realized that one second after posting my question ! But still as in the Edit I would like to delete the `min-height` and use a `background-size:contain` with the img stretching to fit the text height

Comment: Can you use `img` instead of `background` https://jsfiddle.net/pxs8jsmo/7/ ?

Comment: I could, but in your example it fit the `img` width at 100% of the `.image`. And by modifying it by `height:100%;` it display the `img` at 100% of it's own size and not the `.text` height !

Comment: So maximum `height` for image is text `height` ? Why do you need `vertical-align`  then?

Comment: I think i got it this time https://jsfiddle.net/pxs8jsmo/9/ `:)`. Is that it?

Comment: @NenadVracar How did I miss that ? Old trick but works perfectly thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with **CSS tables**

```css
.wrapper {
  display: table;
}

.image{
  width: 20%;
  display: table-cell;
  background: url('https://images.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Ftse1.mm.bing.net%2Fth%3Fid%3DOIP.M3e54c25b2796b134bf010adb75160216H0%26pid%3D15.1&f=1');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.text{
  width: 60%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="image"></div>
  <div class="text">
  "But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure what you mean by `Vertically align`
do you want to put the image above the text?
if so, you need to delete that display : inline-block in .wrapper div
if you want to put the image in the background of the text,
you should use position:absolute to the image class..
and increase the `z-index`,
or simply put your background in text class...

Answer (score 0):

for 2 `inline-block` side by side, `vertical-align` will need a reset. (defaut is `baseline` )

You need a reset to `vertical-align:middle;`

https://jsfiddle.net/pxs8jsmo/8/